# Easily select default usings for project namespaces and subamespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, default-value, preferences, using-statement

Is there an easy way in Visual Studio to assign default usings when i make a new file in a certain (sub)namespace in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new template with File -> Export Template... -> Item Template, but to be honest I never bother - there is a "Remove Unused Usings" option for cleaning down, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> for adding them...

Answer (score 2):

Modify the template file in zip files under
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\"